# Return value 3221225725, possible buffer overflow?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The aim of the exercise is to allocate "n" arrays whose dimensions goes from 2 to n+1 and give them random values to each element of each array
So my idea was to use double pointers to pointers (that can be considered arrays in some way (?) ) Sorry for the italian language but it's an exercise for my school
Anyhow, the code seems teorically correct but it can't do more than 2 cycles, for example it works for n=1,2 but from 3 and on it quits from the cycle and terminates the program, any suggestions to avoid it or to ?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 100

/*The aim of the exercise is to allocate "n" arrays whose dimensions goes from 2 to n+1 and give them random values to each element of each array
So my idea was to use double pointers to pointers (that can be considered arrays in some way (?) ) Sorry for the italian language but it's an exercise for my school
Anyhow, the code seems teorically correct but it can't do more than 2 cycles, for example it works for n=1,2 but from 3 and on it quits from the cycle and terminates the program, any suggestions?*/

int main() {
        int n, i, j = 0, array[MAX];
        int *p1 = NULL, **p2 = NULL;
        srand(time(NULL));
        printf("Inserisci un numero naturale n per allocare un numero n di vettori\ndi lunghezza da 2 a n+1 :\n"); //Write a natural number n to allocate n arrays which contains from 2 to n+1 elements
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("\n\n");
        p2 = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*)); //allocating the space for a double pointer
        for (i = 2; i <= n+1; i++) {
                *p2 = (int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int)); //allocating the space for the pointers
                printf("\nVettore #%d = ", i-1);
                for (j = 0 ;j < i ;j++) {
                        p2[i-2][j] = rand() % 10;
                        printf("%d ", p2[i-2][j]);

                }
                free(*p2);
        }



return 0;


}
```

Comment: It's best to just paste the code into the question using the formatting options available.

Comment: You allocate space for *p2 many times.  That is the same as allocating space for p2[0].  But you never allocate space for p2[i] for i > 0.  Just change the line `*p2 = malloc...` to `p2[i-2] = ...`

Comment: always check the returned code from the scanf() function to assure the associated variables were all successfully updated

Comment: `3221225725 == 0xc00000fd`. Googling for that hex value gives a lot of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
*p2 = (int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int)); //allocating the space for the pointers
```

You want to make an "array of arrays," which is why you are using a double pointer. `int** p2` is meant to be an array of pointers to `int*`, pointers of integers.

So this looks good:

```
p2 = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*)); //allocating space for an array of pointers
```

It is an array of n pointers to `int*`. Now we want each of these pointers to point to array as well. In the `for` loop, use

```
p2[i-2] = (int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int)); //allocating space for one array
```

This should work as you expect. Personally, I would use `i` and `i+2` in my loops instead, but your choice is fine.

Note that you don't need to `free` the allocated memory. It goes away when your program ends. If your assignment requires `free`ing the space, then you need to write another loop to free the memory in each of the `p2[i]` arrays, and then free `p2`.

Also, it is considered a [bad idea](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) to cast the return value from `malloc()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer was perfect and fast. It solved my  problem. I'll keep in mind your advices.